# nm-applet - (dynamically) expand menu size

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, mate, widgets

When having many WiFi SSIDs available, I need to scroll through the right-click menu of `nm-applet` widget menu by hovering over the arrow (see first screenshot below), yet the menu only spreads to a maximum of half my desktops height. Sometimes the size even shrinks in what I can currently only perceive as a random pattern (second screenshot).

How to set the size of this menu and make it use the whole desktop height as maximum before offering to scroll?

Running `mate` as desktop environment in`18.04 LTS`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have Mate Desktop ATM but Install dconf and check if you have height or maximum height settings for nm applet.